# Android Issue in updating APK from Marshmallow to Nougat

Tags: android, file, apk, updates, auto-update

I am writing an app updater program for my app. After that I make sure that I have my own old apk on the device,the updater worked very well till the **MARSH MALLOW** and when the **NOUGAT** version updates, it shows the error, this is what I do from within the app I'm trying to update:

```
       try {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    Uri apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(filepath));
                    intent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The application crashes when trying to open a new existing apk.

this is error log:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/.fTouch_app/Ftouch.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

appreciate for help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html) looks like your problem.

**From the documentation for FileUriExposedException**

> The exception that is thrown when an application exposes a file:// Uri to another app.
>
> This exposure is discouraged since the receiving app may not have access to the shared path. For example, the receiving app may not have requested the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE runtime permission, or the platform may be sharing the Uri across user profile boundaries.
>
> Instead, apps should use content:// Uris so the platform can extend temporary permission for the receiving app to access the resource.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting N or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to share file:// Uri, but it's strongly discouraged.

Comment: @NathaniSoftware Take a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed). It has a couple of very popular answers that may help you out.